# TA-Lib producing NaN's for large inputs (length 1100+)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ta-lib

When using the python TA-Lib library with large arrays (length 2000) I am finding a TA-Lib function (for example BBands) only produces results up til index 1100 then the rest of the result is NaN's.

So for a array of 2000 passed to BBands the final 900 values are NaN's.

I am finding this result consistent across all functions I have tried.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that reproduces this problem?